# yum installs kernel-devel different from my kernel version

Tags: fedora, kernel, yum, vmware

I am attempting to install the VMWare player in Fedora 19. I am running into the problem that multiple users have had where VMware player cannot find the kernel headers. I have installed the `kernel-headers` and `kernel-devel` packages through `yum` and the file that appears in `/usr/src/kernels` is:

```
3.12.8-200.fc19.x86_64
```

However, when I do `uname -r` my Fedora kernel version is:

```
3.9.5-301.fc19.x86_64
```

which is a different version. This seems to mean that when I point VMware player at the path of the kernels I get this error:

```
C header files matching your running kernel were not found.  
Refer to your distribution's documentation for installation instructions.
```

How can I install the correct Kernel and where should I be pointing VMware if its not `/usr/src/kernels/<my-kernel>` ?

Comment: Just curious ... Why aren't you running the latest kernel in Fedora 19?

Comment: Not by a my own decision. I installed from the webiste the latest build that i could. Is there a way to update the kernel?

Comment: Most keep all the packages current by using the Package Manager or as root executing `yum update` from a command line.  Done frequently, and with a decent Internet connection, it doesn't take long, but you've got a bit of catch-up to do.  To use the new kernel, you'll need to reboot after the update is done.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can install the correct kernel header files like so:

```
$ sudo yum install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"
```

#### Example

This command will always install the right version.

```
$ sudo yum install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, changelog, langpacks, refresh-packagekit
No package kernel-devel-uname-r == 3.12.6-200.fc19.x86_64 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Or you can search for them like this:

```
$ yum search "kernel-headers-uname-r == $(uname -r)" --disableexcludes=all
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, changelog, langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Warning: No matches found for: kernel-headers-uname-r == 3.12.6-200.fc19.x86_64
No matches found
```

However I've notice this issue as well where specific versions of headers are not present in the repositories. You might have to reach into Koji to find a particular version of a build.

- [Information for build kernel-3.12.6-200.fc19](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=486642)

That page includes all the assets for that particular version of the Kernel.

Comment: Why is this better than `yum install "kernel-devel-$(uname -r)"`?  From your example, it doesn't even seem to even work...

Comment: @drs - It doesn't work b/c there aren't any matching pkgs that provide the headers for my kernel version. Using the for -uname-r` is a more portable way of doing work w/ pkgs that are tied to the kernel version. It's used on most repos if you look at their examples too: http://rpmfusion.org/Howto/nVidia

Comment: This was really helpful. I thought i had installed the correct version of kernel headers, a very small difference in name, but it was not correct and failing to build. Above command helped me got the actual one as well as give me better insight into package search. Thank you +1

Comment: Is there a way we can make yum/dnf automatically install new kernel headers as well whenever it updates the kernel ?

Comment: @ShankarNarayanan - if you have a new question I encourage you to ask it .

Comment: @slm Thanks. I had asked a similar question few days before. Please find the link here.

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251271/how-to-enable-auto-upgrade-of-kernel-devel-package-when-kernel-version-is-upgrad

Comment: @slm where can I find any information/documentation on this syntax: `"kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"`?

Comment: Is it Fedora-specific or it can work on Centos?

Comment: For anyone getting this for Oracle Linux AND using the UEK kernel, the kernel-headers are in a different package (kernel-uek-devel). The correct call for Oracle Linux UEK Kernel is:



`sudo yum install "kernel-uek-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"`

Answer (score 11):

### Distribution Synchronization

Your problem could be "distribution synchronization". Running this command solved my problem.

```
yum distro-sync
```

> Synchronizes the installed package set with the latest packages
>   available, this is done by either obsoleting, upgrading or downgrading
>   as appropriate. (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html)

Comment: This helped but I just did `sudo yum upgrade kernel`, not the whole distro because it causes some undesired downgrades.

Answer (score 5):

You can install a specific version of a package by specifying the version along with the package name with `yum`.  For example, to install the kernel development files for the specific kernel you're running, type

```
yum install kernel-devel-3.9.5-301.fc19
```

You can do a similar command to get the right `kernel-headers` package.

Answer (score 1):

It happens some times also to me, installing VMBoxAdditions after a system update.

I have to **remove** kernel-devs:

```
yum remove kernel-devel
```

and then re-install it:

```
yum install kernel-devel
```

And **then** magically it works.

Answer (score 1):

I come across the same thing after update the kernel and Jim's answer helped a lot.
To do enable the **[elrepo-kerne]** repo, go to `/etc/yum.repos.d/elrepo.repo` file and set `enabled=1` (rather than `enabled=0`) for **[elrepo-kernel]**, then do the update informed by slm's answer.
After that, reverse to the `enabled=0`, so that the yum will not interact with this repo.
Just to point out, the command `yum repolist all` will show you all enabled and disabled repos.