# Unable to start Virtual Box in Cent OS

Tags: centos, virtualbox

```
[root@localhost sysadmin]# /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                         [  OK  ]
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules            [  OK  ]
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMSError! echo
Your kernel headers for kernel 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.i686 cannot be found at
/lib/modules/2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.i686/build or /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.i686/source.
                                                           [FAILED]
  (Failed, trying without DKMS)
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules                      [FAILED]
  (Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong)
[root@localhost sysadmin]#
```

I am using CentOS 32-Bit version.

Answer (score 1):

Install `kernel-headers` by doing:

```
yum install kernel-headers
```

Also please make sure you are updated and actually running the mentioned kernel (if you updated your kernel, reboot).

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110682/yum-installs-kernel-devel-different-from-my-kernel-version that helped me