# Your kernel headers for kernel 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 cannot be found

Tags: centos, terminal, kernel, linux-kernel, virtualbox

When I type the command `service vboxdrv setup` in my CentOS 7 terminal, I get the following error:

```
Your kernel headers for kernel 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 cannot be found
```

**How can I resolve this error?**

When I open the log file by typing `vi /var/log/vbox-install.log`, the contents are:

```
Uninstalling modules from DKMS
  removing old DKMS module vboxhost version  5.0.4

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 5.0.4
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Attempting to install using DKMS

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/5.0.4/source ->
                 /usr/src/vboxhost-5.0.4

DKMS: add completed.
Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
```

The error is happening in the process of installing VirtualBox 5.0.4 using [the instructions from this tutorial](http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-virtualbox-on-centos-redhat-and-fedora/#).  To summarize, so far, I have:

```
vi /etc/yum.repos.d/virtualbox.repo
```

Add the following text, then save and exit:

```
[virtualbox]
name=Oracle Linux / RHEL / CentOS-$releasever / $basearch - VirtualBox
baseurl=http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/el/$releasever/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc
```

Then at command prompt type:

```
# rpm -Uvh http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/Fedora/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
# yum install gcc make patch  dkms qt libgomp 
# yum install kernel-headers kernel-devel fontforge binutils glibc-headers glibc-devel
...
Complete!  
# cd /usr/src/kernels
# ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root 4096 Sep 25 16:14 .
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root 4096 Sep 25 14:17 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root root 4096 Sep 25 16:14 3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64
# export KERN_DIR=/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64
# yum install VirtualBox-5.0
...
Complete!  
# service vboxdrv setup
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                         [  OK  ]
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules            [  OK  ]
Removing old VirtualBox pci kernel module                  [  OK  ]
Removing old VirtualBox netadp kernel module               [  OK  ]
Removing old VirtualBox netflt kernel module               [  OK  ]
Removing old VirtualBox kernel module                      [  OK  ]
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMSError! echo
Your kernel headers for kernel 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 cannot be found at
/lib/modules/3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64/build or /lib/modules/3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64/source.
                                                       [FAILED]
(Failed, trying without DKMS)
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules                      [FAILED]
(Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong)
```

See above for contents of `vi /var/log/vbox-install.log`

Out of curiousity, I looked in `/lib/modules/` and found the following:

```
[root@localhost kernels]# cd /lib/modules
[root@localhost modules]# ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root 4096 Sep 25 15:58 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 30 root root 4096 Sep 25 16:23 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  7 root root 4096 Sep 25 15:59 3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64
drwxr-xr-x.  8 root root 4096 Sep 25 16:24 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
```

As per @EricRenouf's advice, I typed `uname -a`, and the terminal replied with:

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 6 11:36:42 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have not rebooted the machine, but the tutorial did not say to reboot.

Comment: Did you update your kernel without rebooting at some point or something like that?  Does `uname -a` show `3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64` or `3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64`?  I'm guessing it's the former, but yum installed the headers for the latter.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution is likely to be found [at this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110682/yum-installs-kernel-devel-different-from-my-kernel-version) the short version being, run

```
sudo yum install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"
```

That will install the kernel headers for the version of the kernel you are currently running.

I suspect that at some point you did a `yum update` or similar, and that actually installed a new kernel, but you have not yet started running it.  What is probably happening is that when you do the `yum install` steps in your question it is looking at the latest installed version and getting the headers for that.  Howerver, when you start `vboxdrv` it looks at the running kernel and tries to find the headers for that.

Your running and installed kernels are out of sync (which isn't normally a huge problem), but you found a case where it matters.

Comment: Not working for me. `No package kernel-devel-uname-r == 4.4.193-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 available.`

Comment: @SadikÖzoguz if you are running the version of the kernel you want to install the headers for you can just try `yum install kernel-devel` perhaps that would work easier for you?  If not, you might want to try asking as a new question (perhaps citing this one and giving more information about what your situation is)

Comment: I will ask a new question.

Comment: Saving my day. My home-server had this problem since last year when I updated something. Fortunately I compile only once a year

Answer (score 0):

This issue still occurs on Virtualbox 6.1 and Fedora 32.
My current kernel version and `uname -r` don't match the kernel-headers version.

```
# uname -r 
5.10.17-100.fc32.x86_64+debug

# yum list installed kernel-devel kernel-headers kernel
Installed Packages
kernel.x86_64                                         5.10.17-100.fc32                                  @updates
kernel-devel.x86_64                                   5.10.17-100.fc32                                  
@updates
*kernel-headers.x86_64                                 5.10.13-100.fc32*
```

You can work around this by changing the Virtual box script `/usr/lib/virtualbox/check_module_dependencies.sh`.

In my case I changed the fedora section to reflect the current version of headers I have installed, which DOES match the kernel version im running but is not identical to `uname -r`.
 
ie. ( I've hashed out the original line)

```
case "${UNAME}" in *.fc*.i686|*.fc*.x86_64)  # Fedora
        BASE_PACKAGE="kernel-devel"
        ###VERSIONED_PACKAGE="kernel-devel-${UNAME}"
        VERSIONED_PACKAGE="kernel-devel-5.10.13-100"
```

In the future if there is a new released kernel version that does match the header version you can always remove this is your VirtualBox stops again