# yum doesn't list other versions for kernel in repositories

Tags: centos, kernel, system-installation

I updated my CentOS to kernel version 4.4 (kernel-lt) and want to install `kernel-devel` for the new kernel now.

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/232149/306629) suggests the following command:

```
sudo yum install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"
```

In my case `uname -r` evaluates to `4.4.193-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64`

```
$ sudo yum install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"
[sudo] password for sadik: 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: artfiles.org
 * elrepo: mirrors.nav.ro
 * epel: epel.mirror.nucleus.be
 * extras: mirror.23media.com
 * updates: mirror.fra10.de.leaseweb.net
No package kernel-devel-uname-r == 4.4.193-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

When I look for the source directories, I can only see the ones for version 3.10:

```
$ ls /usr/src/kernels/
3.10.0-1062.1.1.el7.x86_64  3.10.0-1062.1.1.el7.x86_64.debug
```

I tried to look for other versions of `kernel-devel` with the option `--showduplicates`:

```
$ sudo yum search --showduplicates kernel-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: artfiles.org
 * elrepo: fedora.is
 * epel: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
 * extras: mirror.23media.com
 * updates: mirror.fra10.de.leaseweb.net
=========================================================== N/S matched: kernel-devel ===========================================================
kernel-devel-3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.centos.plus.x86_64 : Development package for building kernel modules to match the kernel
kernel-devel-3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64 : Development package for building kernel modules to match the kernel
kernel-devel-3.10.0-1062.1.1.el7.x86_64 : Development package for building kernel modules to match the kernel
kernel-devel-3.10.0-1062.1.1.el7.x86_64 : Development package for building kernel modules to match the kernel
```

How can I install `kernel-devel` or `kernel-headers` for the kernel that is currently running (4.4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you installed the kernel from kernel-lt repo, so you need to make sure you enable that repo to install anything kernel related

```
yum --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel install ...
```