# Your kernel headers for kernel 3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64 cannot be found

Tags: centos, kernel, kernel-modules, dkms

I am tring to install `nvidia driver` by the following command.

```
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-418.43.run --dkms -s
```

Here I got an error as follows.

```
ERROR: Failed to run `/sbin/dkms build -m nvidia -v 418.43 -k 3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64`: Error! echo
   Your kernel headers for kernel 3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64 cannot be found at
   /lib/modules/3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64/build or /lib/modules/3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64/source.
   You can use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located.


ERROR: Failed to install the kernel module through DKMS. No kernel module was installed; please try installing again without DKMS, or check the DKMS logs for more
       information.
```

However, `/lib/modules/3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64/build` and `/lib/modules/3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64/source` are both in my `/lib/modules` path.

```
# cd /lib/modules/3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64
# ls -la
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root     39 7月   2 11:11 build -> /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root      5 7月   2 11:11 source -> build
```

I have tried `sudo yum install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"` in a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232147/your-kernel-headers-for-kernel-3-10-0-229-el7-x86-64-cannot-be-found) which doesn't work, it said

```
No package kernel-devel-uname-r == 3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64 available
```

This is my output of `uname -r`

```
3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64
```

And this is the `kernel` related packages

```
kernel.x86_64                  3.10.0-1062.el7                                                       
kernel.x86_64                  3.10.0-1160.31.1.el7              
kernel-devel.x86_64            3.10.0-1160.31.1.el7                                    
kernel-headers.x86_64          3.10.0-1160.31.1.el7
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you post the output of `lspci | grep 3D`? Forgot to ask: are you running this in a VM or is it bare metal?

Comment: @telometto the output is `1b:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU104GL [Tesla T4] (rev a1)`. I am runnning on a CentOS server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option would appear to be a reboot, so that the running kernel matches the installed headers (1160.31.1).

Otherwise you’d have to find the header package for your older kernel (1062).

Comment: Quite right. Thanks Stephen. I had spent almost a day to find the right answer.