# How to enable auto upgrade of kernel-devel package when kernel version is upgraded?

Tags: fedora, kernel, upgrade

I have a USB wireless adapter for which I need to re-install a kernel module every time the kernel gets upgraded to a new version. But for installing this kernel module again, I need to download and install kernel-devel packages for that kernel version every time.

Is there a way to upgrade kernel-devel packages for a kernel version every time a kernel gets upgraded?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, on Redhat like distros (incl. Fedora), you can use the `yum autoupdate` facility.

`yum-autoupdate.noarch : Automatically update your machine daily via yum`

That will setup by default a daily cron job to run `yum update` on your system, taking care of updating any relevant packages you have that might be out of date, which I guess should also do for `kernel-devel`.

I've found an [article](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/AutoUpdates) on this related to Fedora which talks about this in further details including **why you should enable this feature and also why you shouldn't**!

In this article, there are some interesting points related to kernel update:

> You installed a custom kernel, custom kernel modules, third party kernel modules, or have a third party application that depends on kernel versions (this may not be a problem if you **exclude kernel updates, which is the default in Fedora** `dnf.conf` or `yum.conf` files). (But see also bug [#870790](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=870790) - you may need to modify in Fedora 22 or later versions `/etc/dnf/automatic.conf` in base section to add `exclude=kernel*`. or in Fedora 21 or earlier versions `/etc/yum/yum-cron.conf` to `exclude=kernel*`.)

In your case, you would need to check either `dnf.conf` or `yum.conf` to make sure they include kernel updates.

And also:

> Automatic updates may not complete the entire process needed to make the system secure. For example, dnf or yum can install a kernel update, but until the machine is rebooted (which dnf or yum will not do automatically) the new changes won't take effect. The same may apply to restarting daemons. This can leave the user feeling that he is secure when he is not.