# Your kernel headers for kernel 2.6.32-504.e16.x86_64 cannot be found

Tags: centos, virtualbox, kernel-modules, dkms

I have centos 6.6 installed on virtualbox. In order to use features like copy/paste, being able to share folders, etc, I need to install Guest additions on it.

I've clicked `Device -> Insert Guest Additions CD Image` and then doing the following:

[image]

However, when I try to run `./VBoxLinuxAdditions run` I get the errors below. I am pasting screenshots because I'm not able to copy/paste since I don't have guest addition.

Error:

[image]

Logs:

[image]

The `/lib/modules/2.6.32-504.e16.x86_64/build` and `/lib/modules/2.6.32-504.e16.x86_64/source` folders are both present.

[image]

When I do `yum remove kernel-devel` and install it again using `yum install kernel-devel` this is the version that tries to install. **Note** that it is `2.6.32-573.18.1.e16`

[image]

**What I've done**

Following [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110685) I did `sudo yum install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"` which doesn't work

[image]

Comment: No solution but a question. You*re saying that you downloaded `VBoxGuestAdditions_4.3.14_RC1.iso` and are using this. But in the first screenshot above the version number `5.0.14` is displayed. What is more, it would help if you print the output of `uname -a` (although you already printed this 'indirectly').

Comment: Thats a good catch. And honestly I don't know why it is saying `5.0.14`. I mounted `VBoxGuestAdditions_4.3.14_RC1.iso` and thats the only guest additions iso I have on my host. As for the `uname -a` this is what is the output `2.6.32-504.e16.x86_64`

Answer (score 1):

Your `ls -al /lib/modules/2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64/` command output indicated that the `/lib/modules/2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64/source` is actually a symbolic link to the `build` directory at the same level of the directory tree. Furthermore, the symbolic link is displayed in **red**, indicating that the link is broken, and the link target display (`-> build`) has a **red background**, indicating that the link target does not actually exist.

You also seem to have a newer kernel version `2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64` installed, but not running yet. Although you will usually have multiple kernel versions installed in parallel, the same does not apply to the `kernel-devel` package: it normally tracks the newest distribution kernel you have installed.

My guess is that as `2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64` kernel version was installed, the `kernel-devel` package also got updated to match it. After a reboot, you would be running that kernel version instead of your current one, and then you could again successfully build third-party kernel modules, like the modules of the VirtualBox Guest Additions.

[The answer you linked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110685/258991) uses the `kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)` syntax which was apparently "a stupid hack" [according to Thorsten Leemhuis](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1047041), and may have become obsolete somewhere between Fedora 19 and Fedora 21.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an ISO, can you not just install the Guest Additions using the "Devices" tab, on the machine that is running?

[image: Install Guest Additions]

Comment: This is what I did. I clicked `Devices -> install Guest Additions CD Image`

Comment: And did that work for you? :)

Comment: No. I'm assuming the steps I'm doing are required after I click `Insert Guest Additions CD Image`

Comment: My presumption about the ISO was incorrect. When I click insert Guest additions CD Image. I guess `5.0.14` image gets inserted and then I execute the `./VBoxLinuxAdditions run` command. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: I have just tried doing it as you said, in your updated question, and it is working for me. So not sure what I have that you don't have. Maybe try restarting the system, and see if that fixes the copy/paste issue? Sorry I can't be of any more assistance :)

Comment: You tried 6.6 centos? What did you do after you clicked `install guest additions cd image`?

Comment: Yeah it is CentOS 6.6 (`26.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64`). As I have the GUI, I cancelled the AutoRun and mounted the cdrom, as your steps showed, through the Terminal. Then ran it the same way you did `./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`.

Comment: `cat /etc/centos-release` > `CentOS release 6.6 (Final)`

Comment: And that installed without any issues? Very surprising. did you have to install gcc, make, perl, etc? Can you please provide a link to the ISO or virtualbox image you used for 6.6. I would be OK using the GUI as well. I'll use the same and try a new VM. I've wasted too much time on this. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37278/discussion-between-kevdog777-and-omnipresent).

Comment: FWIW, where you mentioned that /lib/modules/2.6.32-504.e16.x86_64/build is present, but where does that symlink point to ?