# How to install anbox in Fedora 32?

Tags: fedora, android, emulators

### The Problem

I'm trying to install this android emulator using `snap`.

This is what I have done, so far:

- installed anbox, following [instructions in Snapcraft](https://snapcraft.io/install/anbox/fedora);
- installed `kernel-devel`;
- tried to install [kernel modules](https://github.com/anbox/anbox-modules#anbox-kernel-modules).

Although, I was not able to install kernel modules because whenever I install `kernel-devel` it has a different version from my kernel. For example:

- I have this kernel: `5.8.18-200.fc32.x86_64`
- but `kernel-devel` has this version: `5.9.15-100.fc32.x86_64`

And DKMS outputs this:

```
Your kernel headers for kernel `5.8.18-200.fc32.x86_64` cannot be found at
/lib/modules/5.8.18-200.fc32.x86_64/build or /lib/modules/5.8.18-200.fc32.x86_64/source.
```

---

### Details

-> In order to install anbox, I used this:

```
sudo snap install anbox --devmode --beta
```

-> In order to install `kernel-devel`, I am using this:

```
sudo dnf install kernel-devel
```

-> I have tried to install the correct headers using this command, as recommended in [this other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110682/yum-installs-kernel-devel-different-from-my-kernel-version):

```
sudo yum install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"
```

-> Launching anbox doesn't work, even if I use this recommended command:

```
anbox launch --package=org.anbox.appmgr --component=org.anbox.appmgr.AppViewActivity
```

### Question Updates

#### 1. Kernel mismatch

I had to update my OS, to get the new kernel. There's no mismatch problem, anymore.

Before @ajgringo619 hint, I was not able to update it because my `dnf.conf` had an install limit:

```
installonly_limit=1
```

This would result in this error:

```
Error: 
 Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: kernel-core
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

After changing `dnf.conf`, I was able to update my kernel and solve mismatch issues.

#### 2. Unable to install anbox modules

I'm still unable to install modules. Now, due to [modpost error](https://github.com/anbox/anbox-modules/issues/67).

Comment: Until you get the kernel package mismatch fixed, you're probably stuck. Try running `sudo dnf distro-sync`.

Comment: @ajgringo619 Updating my OS solved mismatch problems. Although, I'm still unable to install modules. Now, due to modpost error. https://github.com/anbox/anbox-modules/issues/67

Comment: This is one of the downsides of distros that run the latest-and-greatest kernels. Have you tried a Ubuntu-based release? At least Anbox supports them.

Comment: Are you talking about dropping Fedora and installing Ubuntu? This is something had not considered.

Comment: I suggested Ubuntu for (2) reasons: Anbox supports it, and the kernel isn't as new.